# Accessing Associations in a View with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations

Sorry if this question is too vague, but I'd rather not muddy it's point with my assumptions as to what may or may not actually be relevant background information.

If I create an association such as Employee belongsTo Company

When I create a view for Employee and want to display their Company name how can I simply display the company name by...

```
<?php echo $employee['Employee']['Company']['company_name'] ?>
```

or simply a custom property (if such a thing exist) such as...

```
<?php echo $employee['Employee']['CompanyName'] ?>
```

This, of course, assumes the use of...

```
$this->set('employee',$someEmployeeRetreivalLogicHere)
```

...in the Controller

Comment: The first thing you want to familiarize yourself with in Cake is the structure of query results. As dhofstet points out, do a couple of `debug()` on the results of different queries.

Comment: Yeah, thought I had it down, but apparently I didn't. I'm running on the default layout, which shows the sql being sent to the db. I think I need to understand how cakephp retrieves data better, because the sql statements I'm seeing are only on the employees table and don't include any joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be accessible with:

```
<?php echo $employee['Company']['company_name'] ?>
```

If that doesn't work, use debug($employee); to see the array's structure.

Comment: Just adding: this of course requires that the record was retrieved with an appropriate `recursive` setting.

Comment: So in your example say Employee has a date property called "hired", I could access this by "$employee['Employee']['hired']" or would it be "$employee['hired']"

Also the default recursive setting is 0 right?

Comment: @Antilogic: It would be $employee['Employee']['hired']

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be the case, I'm able to do $employee['Employee']['hired'] but not $employee['Company']['company_name']. I get a Notice (8): Undefined index:  Company